# Why stripe api doesn't generate 3d confirmation link on out off-session payment

Tags: .net, stripe-payments

I'm starting a subscription using the stripe api. First, I get tokens for the card with the payment element. Then I create a payment method with that token. Then I attach it to the customer.

After all, I'm setting a TrialEnd when create a subscription. So the payment will be session-off. Works fine on successful test cards. But in a payment that requires 3d, when it tries to withdraw money from the card with '4000000000003063', it declines the card. And it doesnt attempt to confirm 3d secure. I have to add new payment method for this payment.
[image]

If I add the payment method (same card as the previous one) via the stripe dashboard, the card again declines. But stripe generates a link to just confirm the payment. It doesn't want to add a new payment method.(just confirm 3d via stripe hosted link)
[image]

I don't know what there is a difference between adding the card from the dashboard and adding it on the API.

So I just want to confirm 3d payment via stripe-hosted-link without add new payment method.

associated stripe link:
https://support.stripe.com/questions/subscription-retries-for-failed-3d-secure-authorizations

Like:

[image]

Thanks in advance for your help..

Comment: Can you clarify the question? What specifically is the issue? What you're describing seems expected – if the payment if off-session and 3DS/authentication is requested then the payment will in theory be a decline, the intent will transition to `requires_payment_method` and you'll need to bring your customer back on-session to retry payment.

Comment: Hi Jonathan. There is no problem with the card being a decline. The problem is: the payment requires an extra confirmation. Stripe sends a stripe-hosted-link for this via email or webhook. Through this link, the customer must go to the bank page and confirm 3d. but the link is waiting for the customer to enter a new card. whereas stripe can only send a link pending 3d approval

Comment: https://invoice.stripe.com/i/acct_1NSEtHKabqKT1OUx/test_YWNjdF8xTlNFdEhLYWJxS1QxT1V4LF9PUHpURlN6cXZMNlgxZkN5QVJCdk41ZlJLT25YRGxiLDgyMTE3MzE00200iWwsKpTW?s=db

this link was created by stripe in test mode. (this is not what i want).

https://invoice.stripe.com/i/acct_1NSEtHKabqKT1OUx/test_YWNjdF8xTlNFdEhLYWJxS1QxT1V4LF9PUHdPUkJ2aUx4T0xJZUt3QnJla1RGS25HYkVSZFJkLDgyMTE3NTIw0200sB8a3mLU?s=db

this link was created by stripe in test mode. (as I want).

Comment: The first link comes when I create the payment method on stripe dashboard. but the second one comes when I create payment method via api.

Comment: It's likely because of what I explained above. I suspect the Dashboard initiated invoice is in a `requires_action` status and therefore only requires re-confirmation. The API initiated invoice is in a `requires_payment_method` status as it was likely initiated off-session (and is therefore a decline). This cannot be controlled.

Comment: It could be. but i still can't get it clear: Except for adding a payment method, when I do all the operations (customer creation, subscription creation, etc.) via the api, stripe generates the link I want. but when I add the payment method via the api, it does not generate the link I want.(By the way, in two ways, the card becomes decline. you can see it in the TimeLine pictures above)

Answer (score 0):

I contacted a person in the stripe team. and he said:
"attaching payment methods to customer objects via the API is never meant to trigger 3DS flows. You should use the Setup Intents API to setup payment methods for future use. That way if 3DS is required, it'll be requested".

So we have to use Setup Intents API for resolve this issue